# How Can I get all the columns for joined table using dataprovider in Yii?

Tags: activerecord, orm, yii

My Controller

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria -> select = 't.*,b.*';
$criteria -> join = 'INNER JOIN tbl_b b on b.b_id = t.id ';
$criteria -> join .= 'INNER JOIN tbl_c c on c.id = b.c_id';
$criteria -> condition = 'c.id = :cid';
$criteria -> params = array(':cid' => 1);
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('tbl_a',array(
            'criteria' => $criteria
        ));
$this->render('view',array('dataProvider' => $dataProvider));
```

My View

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
'id' => 'my-grid',
'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
'columns' => array(
    'name',
    'description',
    array(
        'header' => 'Column from tbl_b',
        'value' => ''
    ),      
        array(
        'class'=>'CButtonColumn',
        'template' => '{view}'
), ),));
```

My Question is: **How can I display value of column** from `tbl_b`. Since in `dataprovider`, I have specified `tbl_a`, it is pulling the data from `tbl_a` only and not `tbl_b` though I have selected all the records from `tbl_b` as well.

From what I have learned, it should display as `$data -> tbl_b -> col_b`. But this is giving error as `tbl_a.tbl_b` is not defined. **I wonder what is the problem?**

`Is it something regarding the relation?` `tbl_a` and `tbl_c` are related `MANY_MANY` through `tbl_b`. i.e `tbl_b` has two column linking the primary id of `tbl_a` and `tbl_c`.

Note: name and description are from tbl_a and they are displayed.

Please suggest!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What I do usually for this kind of thing is making an attribute in the ActiveRecord.

```
class A extends CActiveRecord {

    public $bAttribute1

}
```

When I join table `A` with table `B`, I rename the field from `B` that I want to show with the attribute I created (in this case, the `bAttribute`)

```
$dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('A', array(
    'criteria' => array(
        'select' => array('t.*', 'b.attribute1 AS bAttribute1'),
        'join' => 'JOIN B AS b ON b.joinId = t.id',
    )
));
```

Then I could show the `bAttribute1` in the GridView,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'bAttribute1',  
)));
```

This should be working. But the downside is that you have to create a lot of attributes if you want to show a lot of columns from the joined table.

**UPDATE**

Weird,, so I tried to make example from scratch. I created two tables `ModelA` and `ModelB` like below.

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ModelA` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute2` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute3` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `ModelB` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `aId` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute3` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `attribute4` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

As you can see, the `aId` in `ModelB` is a foreign key to `ModelA`. And then I put some examples.

```
INSERT INTO `ModelA` (`id`, `attribute2`, `attribute3`) VALUES
(1, 1, 1),
(2, 2, 2);
INSERT INTO `ModelB` (`id`, `aId`, `attribute3`, `attribute4`) VALUES
(1, 1, 10, 100),
(2, 2, 20, 200),
(3, 1, 30, 300),
(4, 1, 40, 400);
```

So, entry #1 in `ModelA` will be referenced by 3 entries in `ModelB` while entry #2 will have only 1.

Then I created the model code.

```
class ModelA extends CActiveRecord {
    public $bAttribute3;
    public $bAttribute4;
    public static function model($className = __CLASS__) {
            return parent::model($className);
    }
}
```

See the `bAttribute3` and `bAttribute4` in the model, I put the `attribute3` and `attribute4` from `ModelB` table there, respectively. Then in the controller I created the DataProvider

```
public function actionIndex(){
    $dataProvider = new CActiveDataProvider('ModelA', array(
        'criteria' => array(
            'select' => array(
                '`t`.*', 
                '`b`.`attribute3` AS `bAttribute3`',
                '`b`.`attribute4` AS `bAttribute4`'
            ),
            'join' => 'JOIN `ModelB` AS `b` ON `b`.`aId` = `t`.`id`',
        )
    ));
    $this->render('index', array(
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    ));
}
```

And in the view, I make this

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'my-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'attribute2',
        'attribute3',
        'bAttribute3',
        'bAttribute4',
    ),
));
```

So, here is what I see

[image: Imgur]

Is it what you want? I usually do it this way even for CActiveDataProvider. I think you might miss something in your code.

Comment: I tried this.... and I think this should work but it didn't. The dataProvider does not contain the value of locally created variable. It only have the records from the tblA and not bAttribute1. What can be the problem? Is it something I am missing again or the solution does not work? When I tried the query it works fine! Just does not when using dataprovider.

Comment: I updated my answer. I tried making one from scratch, and it works.

Comment: Wow!! That was a great answer! But my situation is little different as I have mentioned in my question. table A and table c are not connected directly so they don't have foreign relationship. They are connected together by tableB. TableB contain primary key of tableA and tableC and relate them. I know this sound little weird but I have to maintain foreign relationship this way. So, for this condition what can be the solution? Your code is correct if they have direct relationship but in my case, it is not. So, any suggestion on this scenario?

Comment: actually, its pretty much the same,, you just need to add another attribute, let's say `cAttribute1` and in the selection you just rename the field `c.attribute1 AS cAttribute1`,,

Comment: have you tried in the column like this `'value' => '$data->tableC->attribute1`?

Comment: Yes, I have tried $data -> tablC -> attribute1. It will give me error as tableA.tableC is not defined. I am not sure of the cause of this error. But I have very instinct that it is due to the relation in model. I am certain that your solution is correct but it just does not work on my condition. Still could not fetch the record for model except the one we provide as argument in CActiveDataProvider. I just could not figure it out!!

Comment: I forgot to pull the record in the select criteria that's why it is popping up with so many error. Stupid Me... My Bad!! Thanks for your help Petra.... Appreciate It!!